# Hacer click boton con Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

Hola soy nuevo con `Selenium`. Este es el código del **boton** donde deseo hacer **click**:

```
<a href="javascript:bp(26834)">Clic para ver</a>
```

Navego hasta la página indicada pero no se reflaja la accion de **click** que debería mostrar un dato oculto. Este el código que utilizo:

```
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='bt']")
login_attempt.click()
```

Les agradecería su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Juan, si es posible y no es un problema, proveer un link a la pagina concreta puede ser de gran ayuda para dar una posible respuesta que funcione con seguridad en tu caso. Una opción es ejecutar el código javascript directamente `browser.execute_script("bp(26834)")`, para ver como hacerlo vía `click` se necesita conocer la estructura real de la página para ver como encontrar el elemento.

Comment: probe tu sugerencia y nada :( aqui esta la web de donde quiero mostar el num http://www.compraensanjuan.com/sitio/73744/ricardo-monte/9/1/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como señala [@FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla) la mejor opción es ejecutar el comando que realiza con `javascript:bp(26834)`, pero para ello debes esperar que cargue la pagina, el siguiente código muestra como hacerlo.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'http://www.compraensanjuan.com/sitio/73744/ricardo-monte/9/1/1'
browser.get(url)

timeout = 3

try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'bt')))
    browser.execute_script("bp(26834)")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Se vencio el timeout")
```

Si deseas usar xPath un posible valor es `//a[contains(text(),'Clic para ver')]`:

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'bt')))
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Clic para ver')]")
elem.click()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudar a este novato.

Comment: @JuanOntivero yo tambien soy novato en selenium :-)

Comment: Hay un  detalle a tener en cuenta para la primera opción, el argumento a la función JavaScript es variable ya que es la "id" del usuario/sitio, en este caso 73744 (compraensanjuan.com/sitio/ **73744** /ricardo-monte). Si se llama con otra id válida se genera también el teléfono y se muestra en su lugar, pero es el teléfono de otro usuario. Para este link la llamada debe ser `"bp(73744)"` por tanto. Si tenemos que generalizar esto para cualquier usuario, podríamos en principio  obtener la id del mismo link y formatear la cadena de llamada a la función JavaScript.

Comment: @FJSevilla okay, bueno no me había percatado, pero si revisas lo que indicas no es parte de la  pregunta. Eso debería ser parte de la investigación del OP ¿no crees?

Answer (score 1):

El problema realmente es que haces click en el `div`, no en el link que contiene. Puedes seleccionar el `<div>` por `id` como haces ahora y luego seleccionar el elemento `<a>` a partir de el, por ejemplo usando XPATH.

Posteriormente, si tu objetivo final es obtener el teléfono como supongo, hay que esperar a que la llamada a la función de JavaScript se procese. Dado que en este punto el hiperlink anterior desaparece, podemos usarlo con un *wait* implícito para saber cuando está disponible el texto con el teléfono.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



timeout = 10
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.compraensanjuan.com/sitio/73744/ricardo-monte/9/1/1")

try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    div = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'bt')))
    wait = WebDriverWait(div, timeout)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//a"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/a')))

except TimeoutException:
    print("Tiempo de espera superado")

else:
    print("El teléfono es {}".format(div.text))

driver.close()
```

Se puede seleccionar directamente el elemento a mediante XPATH de varias formas, por ejemplo con:

```
"//div[@id='bt']//a"
```

Pero dado que necesitamos el `div` para obtener el teléfono al final nos compensa hacerlo en dos pasos.